# Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "user". Unexpected keys will be ignored

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux-toolkit

I am trying to use Redux to update a users profile. I keep getting the error

```
Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "user". Unexpected keys will be ignored.
```

I have my store created with this:

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userProfileReducer from './slices/user';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userProfileReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

The userSlice is below which is getting the error. I am passing the initial state and then using that to send to the reducer:

```
const initialUserState = {
  user: {
    email: '',
    name: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    isAdmin: false,
  },
};

const UserSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: initialUserState,
  reducers: {
    user(state, action) {
      state.email = action.payload.email;
      state.name = action.payload.name;
      state.isAdmin = action.payload.isAdmin;
      state.phoneNumber = action.payload.phoneNumber;
    },
  },
});

export const userActions = UserSlice.actions;
export default UserSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem that I can spot is that you have one level of too deep nesting. It should be:

```
const initialUserState = {
  email: '',
  name: '',
  phoneNumber: '',
  isAdmin: false,
};
```

Does this solve the above problem?

Comment: No unfortunately that is the same error. I did think about the nesting.

Comment: Don't know what you did but I've verified in that Code Sandbox that the above is the fix: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-73817607-kycs8b

Comment: Yes that is calling the state but the issue is that its not updating the reducer. My dispatch is: 
 dispatch(user({
              email: email,
              name: name,
              phone: phoneNumber,
              password: password,
              isAdmin: true,
            }));